# Unable to locate elements via Selenium if ran via Bitbucket pipeline

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, bitbucket-pipelines

I am currently working on integration tests in Selenium. I have some testset, which tests presence of webelements and their behaviour. Everything works perfectly if I run these tests on my local machine. As a WebDriver I use ChromeDriver.

But some of these tests fail, if I run them in pipeline on bitbucket. It fails because it was not able to locate element, the worst thing is that in pipeline it behaves sort of undeterministic - that it sometimes locate this element and sometimes it doesn't (no code changed between run in which element was found and in which element was not found, Website tested was not changed either between runs.)

> Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of element located by... (tried for 300 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

On my local machine, which is not really fast one, 30s timeout is perfectly enough for me. And tests always pass on my local machine. Is it that pipeline on bitbucket runs extremely slowly or do I miss something?

```
webDriver.get(getTerminalUrl());
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 60);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[text()='Sign In']")));
WebElement login = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Sign In']"));
login.click();
```

I use this kind of pattern in all my tests.

Comment: Can you add your code snippet?

Comment: In comments code is a bit broken and hardly readable, I will add it to my question.

Comment: WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(webDriver,30);
WebElement we = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[text()='Sign In']"))); we.click(); can you check with above code.

Comment: @Girish Thank you. But sadly same problem, now it is not saying waiting for presence but waiting for visibility. On local machine both visibility and presence pass all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing like this:

```
webDriver.get(getTerminalUrl());
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 60);

boolean elementPresent = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[text()='Sign In']")).size() > 0;

if(elementPresent){
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    WebElement login = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Sign In']"));
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    login.click();
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works. I found out, that the button is sometimes not clicked by selenium, but your approach seems to work all the time. Can you briefly explain me please, why Thread.sleep() works better than wait.until()?

Comment: @Jirx, although Thread.sleep() is not preferable because it will make the script sleep for specified time even the element has been found, but as we dont know how much maximum it takes for element to appear in your case , that is why I have suggested this approach.